# Django shows datetime different then system datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

When i check "`datetime.today().date()`" in my `views.py` i get yesterday's date.

But when I check the date from linux system with "`date`" command i get today's date. I think Django is not updating current date. I have to get current date in the view to make some comparisons, also to print into the view.

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.9.

```
def assistant_page(request, assistant=None):
    notes = AssistantNotes.objects.filter(notedate=datetime.today().date()).order_by("time")
    file_write(datetime.today().date())
    if request.method == 'GET':    
        return render(request, "assistant_page.html", {'generalnotes': notes})
```

Comment: Have you specified your time zone in `Settings.py` file?

Comment: Thanks my friend.  it was TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'  i changed it to TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/london' and it is solved now. If you want you can add it as an answer and i accept it.

Comment: Welcome Brother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Time_Zone` setting to your location specific-

As you said yours is **Europe/london**. Therefore add this setting in your

`settings.py`

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/london'
```

Answer (score 0):

Django uses it's own timezone. you can set it in your settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/london'
```

this change your whole project timezone. Another way is to use pytz lib. every datetime object has method astimezone. you can convert datetime object to another timezone easily by:

```
d = datetime.now()
d.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/london'))
```